# travis-ci could not parse yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, travis-ci, deploying

I want to do AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment. But tvavis say "could not parse"
This happens after adding the part of the code that begins with the word "deploy"

```
sudo: required
services:
    - docker
before_install:
    - docker build -t alex-sbk/docker-react -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
    - docker run -e CI=true alex-sbk/docker-react npm run test 

    deploy:
    provider: elasticbeanstalk
    region: "us-east-2"
    app: "docker-react"
    env: "DockerReact-env"
    bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-282895571233"
    bucket_path: "docker-react"
    on:
        branch: master
access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

There are apparent issues with **indentations**. You code does not pass **YAML format** validators. I fixed it a bit, and now it passes

```
--- 
before_install: 
  - "docker build -t alex-sbk/docker-react -f Dockerfile.dev ."
script: 
  - "docker run -e CI=true alex-sbk/docker-react npm run test"
  - 
    deploy: 
      access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
      app: docker-react
      bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-282895571233
      bucket_path: docker-react
      env: DockerReact-env
      provider: elasticbeanstalk
      region: us-east-2
      secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
      true: 
        branch: master
services: 
  - docker
sudo: required
```

The format should be OK now, but I can't guarantee that the deployment will successed. There could be other issue with actual data provided.